# Ruby on rails datetime timezone issue (2h surplus)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, timezone

I'm having issue with timezone in Ruby on Rails project that I'm currently working on.

Problem is that when I save datetime in database table when retrieving that data through API I get 2h surplus which shouldn't be.

I checked postgres database and there timezone is UTC.

```sql
user=# SHOW TIMEZONE;

 TimeZone 
----------
 Etc/UTC
```

Then I check server timezone and is also UTC.

```bash
dpkg-reconfigure tzdata

Current default time zone: 'Etc/UTC'
Local time is now:      Thu Feb 22 08:32:00 UTC 2024.
Universal Time is now:  Thu Feb 22 08:32:00 UTC 2024.
```

Then I checked Ruby on Rails timezone and it's also UTC:

```
# application.rb
config.time_zone = 'UTC'

root@a2d423f6b3ca:~# bundle exec rails console
Loading development environment (Rails 6.1.7.6)
[3] pry(main)> Time.now
=> 2024-02-22 08:27:43.391039472 +0000
```

I know that this part of code in serializer is causing issue (in_time_zone):

```
      def measured_at
        object.try(:raw_measured_at).try(:to_datetime).try(:in_time_zone).try(:strftime, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
      end
```

Thing is that when storing datetime using API frontend or mobile app should send it in UTC and when retrieving also. Then on frontend or mobile app is to calculate in which timezone is user and calculate correct time.
Even when everything is configured to UTC+0 I'm not sure why `:in_time_zone` is causing surplus of 2h.

Example of problem:

Mobile is using POST route to save datetime in UTC+0 `"sinced_at": "2015-04-23 09:12:23"`. Same value is stored in postgresql table. When using GET route to retrieve datetime response is `"synced_at": "2015-04-23 11:12:23" (2h surplus)

By removing `:in_time_zone` api response is `"measured_at": "2015-04-23 09:12:23"

Ruby version: 3.0.4p208
Rails version: 6.1.7.6

Comment: @dbugger I edited question and added the example. I'm not sure either. Agency put my on project but I'm Laravel and NodeJs dev uahahah.

Comment: Sounds like you solved the issue -- since you are only working in UTC no need to modify the raw result.  The in_time_zone method can also be supplied with the UTC timezone explicitly. As written, it is using the default, which is Time.zone. Curious what that returns.  Also what version of Ruby are you using?

Comment: @dbugger Ruby version: `3.0.4p208` Rails version: `6.1.7.6`

Comment: @dbugger Thank you, I will go that way then. I hope it wont result in too much new bugs later because there is no tests.

Comment: An opportunity to add a few :)

Comment: _"Then I checked Ruby on Rails timezone"_ – not quite, `Time.now` returns Ruby’s time which is your machine’s time. You have to use `Time.zone.now` or `Time.current` to get Rails’ time.

Comment: @Stefan you are right, but in my case Time.zone.now and Time.now return same value. `Time.zone.now
=> Fri, 23 Feb 2024 08:30:18.224697179 UTC +00:00`
`Time.now
=> 2024-02-23 08:30:21.003709263 +0000`

Comment: Yeah, the problem is probably outside of the code you've shared. Can you include a [mre], i.e. some code that we can run which results in that 2 hour offset?